# Ajax submiting a form with enter and onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, enter

I have a problem in my code. I've been trying to design a form that could update data in a database and showing it without refreshing the page. I could do this, but I wanted that the form would work if the user pressed the Enter key. 
Here is my code:

```
    <form name="chat" id="chat">
        <textarea name="message" type="text" id="message" size="63" ></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="send();"/>
    </form>
<script>
//This function will display the messages
function showmessages(){
   //Send an XMLHttpRequest to the 'show-message.php' file
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET","chat.php?jogo=<?php echo $numerojogo;?>",false);
      xmlhttp.send(null);
   }
   else{
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      xmlhttp.open("GET","chat.php",false);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
   //Replace the content of the messages with the response from the 'show-messages.php' file
   document.getElementById('chatbox').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   //Repeat the function each 30 seconds
   setTimeout('showmessages()',30000);
}
//Start the showmessages() function
showmessages();
//This function will submit the message
function send(){
   //Send an XMLHttpRequest to the 'send.php' file with all the required informations~
   var sendto = 'adicionar.php?message=' + document.getElementById('message').value + '&jogador=<?php echo $user;?>' + '&jogo=<?php echo $numerojogo;?>';
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
      xmlhttp.send(null);
      document.getElementById("chat").reset();
   }
   else{
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      xmlhttp.open("GET",sendto,false);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
   var error = '';
   //If an error occurs the 'send.php' file send`s the number of the error and based on that number a message is displayed
   switch(parseInt(xmlhttp.responseText)){
   case 1:
      error = 'The database is down!';
      break;
   case 2:
      error = 'The database is down!';
      break;
   case 3:
      error = 'Don`t forget the message!';
      break;
   case 4:
      error = 'The message is too long!';
      break;
   case 5:
      error = 'Don`t forget the name!';
      break;
   case 6:
      error = 'The name is too long!';
      break;
   case 7:
      error = 'This name is already used by somebody else!';
      break;
   case 8:
      error = 'The database is down!';
   }
   if(error == ''){
      $('input[type=text]').attr('value', '');
      showmessages();
   }
   else{
      document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = error;
   }
}
</script>
```

I've tried to put onsubmit instead of onclick but without success :/

EDIT:
Already solved I'm so dumb.. Thank you for the help misko!
Here is my code in case you're having the same trouble as me:

```
<form name="chat" id="chat" onsubmit="send();return false;">
    <input name="message" type="text" id="message" size="63" ></input>
    <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="send();"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works *onclick* I think that *onsubmit* in `<form>` should work too:

> ```
> <form name="chat" id="chat" onsubmit="send();">
>     <textarea name="message" type="text" id="message" size="63" ></textarea>
>     <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="send();"/>
> </form>
> ```

Have you tried that this way?

Comment: Just nailed it thank you so much! I had to add return false but it worked out well!

Comment: You're right, you have to return false, so the form will not really submit, but only execute the *send()* method with AJAX request inside.

Answer (score 1):

---

You will need to add an event listener on that input field. See http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ and my example below.

```js
$( "#message" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     send();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach. 
Determines if carriage return has been pressed. (Ascii 13)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").keydown(function(event){ 
     if(event.which == 13) {
        event.preventdefault();
        // submit
     }
    });
});
```